# pyqt4: Open website in standard browser on button click

Tags: browser, operating-system, pyqt4

I would like to open website in standard browser of operating system when user clicks a button in my pyqt4 application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use the python webbrowser module

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`QDesktopServices::openUrl`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl%60).

Here's the minimal working example,

```py
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QUrl, QDesktopServices
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
url = QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684857/pyqt4-open-website-in-standard-browser-on-button-click")
QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
```

Comment: For PyQt6 the imports are:
`from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl`  
`from PyQt6.QtGui import QDesktopServices`